# Which method is correct for data insertion into database

Tags: java, spring, lambda

I am inserting into database as below.

```
private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO 
ARTICLE_TAG_RELATION(ARTICLE_ID, TAG_ID) VALUES (?, ?)";


private final JdbcTemplate template;


//method 1
void addTags(String articleId, List<String> tags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(String tag:tags){
        template.update(INSERT_SQL, ps-> {
            ps.setString(1, articleId);
            ps.setString(2, tag);
        });
    }

}

//method 2
void addTags(String articleId, List<String> tags) {
    template.update(
                INSERT_SQL, 
        (/*PreparedStatement*/ ps) -> {
            for(String tag:tags){
                        ps.setString(1, articleId);
                        ps.setString(2, tag);
            }
        });
}
```

which method is correct 1 or 2. Or are both the same. Also i dont understand the second method well.

Answer (score 0):

The first method. BTW, this has nothing to do with lambdas. The second approach is going to keep on overwriting previous statement values and only the last tag is going to be inserted. Here is the same version of code without lambda:

```
getJdbcTemplate().update(INSERT_SQL, new PreparedStatementSetter() {

        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

            ps.setString(1, articleId);
            ps.setString(2, tag);
        }
    });
```

Apparently loop inside setValues does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In method 1 you generate many sql insert queries but you can insert multiple rows in one query.

Query syntax:

```
INSERT INTO 
ARTICLE_TAG_RELATION(ARTICLE_ID, TAG_ID) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), ...
```

You need ArrayList `list` that holds String array of articleId and tag. In java 7 it would be like:

```
int position=1;
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
         String[] articleTag = list.get(i);
         preparedStatement.setString(position++,articleTag[0]);
         preparedStatement.setString(position,articleTag[1]);
    }
```